# snmpbulkwalk returning a string in PHP table. How to separate?

Tags: php

Sorry been working this data for hours and can come up with a way to make this work.

I'm performing a php shell_exec snmpbulkwalk.

Example:

```
 $counts = shell_exec("/bin/snmpbulkwalk -v 2c $hostname ..... | awk  '{print \$4}' ");
```

I'm trying to print it in a table.

Example:

```
print "<table border=1 bgcolor=#ffffff>"; 
print "<tr>
       <td>Counts</td>
       </tr>"; 

for ($i=0; $i<count($counts); $i++) {
         print "<tr>";
         print "<td>$counts[$i]</td>";
print "</tr>"; } 
print "</table>";
```

The is resulting in the snmpbulkwalk data being put in one cell.

Example:

```
Counts
890 718 600 577 602 309 924 685 651 204 485 709 341 369 3 39 728 638 556 3 1013 639 476 591 672 774 307 736 586 507 539 467 684 609 760 839 721 735 431 795 868 491 587 581 575 414 299 234
```

I was looking for each value to be in its own row.

Example:

```
Counts
890 
718 
600 
577 
...
```

This seems basic but I'm not sure I understand how to fix.

I know in the past if displayed with the php echo below.  However I need to pull this data into a table.

Example:

```
echo "<pre>".$counts."</pre>"
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: after `shell_exec` use `$counts = explode(" ",$counts);` it get array for table.